# SQL QUERY CASE WHEN EXISTS ADD MULTIPLE

Tags: sql, case, sql-server-2016

i need to add one more sub query to check in the **customertype**  column below is the query how to add to my original query

```
CASE 
  WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT ItemCode
      FROM ORIN
      INNER JOIN RIN1 ON ORIN.DocEntry = RIN1.DocEntry
      WHERE CardCode = X.CardCode
        AND ItemCode = X.ItemCode
        AND ORIN.DocDate < X.[Trans Date]
        AND year(X.[Trans Date]) >= year(getdate()) - 4
      )
    THEN 'Existing'
  ELSE 'OMP'
  END )
```

below is my original query

```
SELECT 
   X.#
  ,(
    CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS (
          SELECT ItemCode
          FROM OINV
          INNER JOIN INV1 ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry
          WHERE CardCode = X.CardCode
            AND ItemCode = X.ItemCode
            AND OINV.DocDate < X.[Trans Date]
            AND year(X.[Trans Date]) >= year(getdate()) - 4
          )
        THEN 'Existing'
      ELSE 'OMP'
      END
    ) AS CustomerType
FROM InvoiceData X
```

my objective is two check both exists in the column customertype. its basically two select query checking

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Your question isn't clear: Are you trying to check which customers are Existing/OMP customers from the InvoiceData table? And the only way you can label them is based on the case statements with the join inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I believe you can include both sub-queries with an `AND`.

```
SELECT 
   X.#
  ,(
    CASE 
      WHEN 
        EXISTS 
          (
          SELECT ItemCode
          FROM OINV
          INNER JOIN INV1 ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry
          WHERE CardCode = X.CardCode
            AND ItemCode = X.ItemCode
            AND OINV.DocDate < X.[Trans Date]
            AND year(X.[Trans Date]) >= year(getdate()) - 4
          )
        AND
        EXISTS 
          (
          SELECT ItemCode
          FROM ORIN
          INNER JOIN RIN1 ON ORIN.DocEntry = RIN1.DocEntry
          WHERE CardCode = X.CardCode
            AND ItemCode = X.ItemCode
            AND ORIN.DocDate < X.[Trans Date]
            AND year(X.[Trans Date]) >= year(getdate()) - 4
          )
        THEN 'Existing'
      ELSE 'OMP'
      END
    ) AS CustomerType
FROM InvoiceData X
```